# Are a class's methods stored only once in memory?

Tags: object-oriented

When I create an instance of a class the system allocates memory for all instance variables of the class. Some languages may call them fields or properties.

But what about the code of the class methods? Are those duplicated too or do I have the code only once in memory? I know all instances got their own values - even inside the methods - but I would like to know about the code.

Do I have instance variables and separate "instance methods"?

Comment: This depends not just on the programming language but in most cases also on its implementation. You need to be more specific.

Comment: @Philipp Far less so than with many other things. In fact, I can't think of a single serious language implementation that duplicates the methods' code, nor for a reason why one might want to.

Comment: Javascript allows you to modify methods for individual instances.  I don't know the details of how it is implemented.

Comment: @delnan: Lua makes it easy to accidentally give each instance it's own copy of the type's methods.

Comment: @delnan: Indeed, javascript, just like Lua, may also end up making copies of methods. Depending on how that method was defined. You have to remember that methods in javascript are just functions (generally anonymous functions) and functions are just closures. Therefore the programmer may WANT to have the class make new copies of a method for each instance of an object.

Comment: @MooingDuck There's a slight difference between the language implementation doing it and the user doing it, even if accidentally. Also, even if you add "the method" to each instance, you really only duplicate the reference and not the function code itself, even if it's a closure.

Comment: @slebetman I'm aware of the possibility to *want* to make "methods" instance attributes, but when the programmer explicitly does it, I don't count that under language implementation behavior. And here too, at worst you duplicate the *reference* to the closure (and perhaps the closed-over variables, if any), not the function code itself.

Comment: @delnan: I checked, in places where I thought I was duplicating methods, lua was smart enough to use references.  I stand corrected.  (hooray for sane languages!)

Answer (score 6):

> Do I have instance variables and separate "instance methods"?

Generally no. Methods belong to the class itself and look like C# extension methods under the hood:

```
void Foo(this T instance, param, param, param)
```

so that `x.Foo(a,b,c)` really gets called like `Foo(x,a,b,c)`. That said, certain languages/implementations allow replacing the methods, so can allocate space for a pointer to *which* `Foo` to use, but even in those cases the language makes those methods *look* like variables (since they effectively **are** variables).

Comment: In some languages methods may carry with it a closure. Therefore the language allow the programmer to assign new instances of the method so that each object carry with it the right closure (for example methods assigned in the constructor as `this.method = function () ...` in javascript).

Comment: In the case of methods carrying a closure, the closure should be given as a parameter to the actual code of the method, just like the object data is given as a parameter to the implmentation of an instance method.  There is no reason to duplicate the code.

Answer (score 5):

In layman's terms:

- Methods are not part of the "state" of an object
- They are part of the blueprint
- They are part of the cookie cutter, not the dough
- They belong to the class, not the instance
- Hence I guess they are stored in memory once

Comment: In some languages methods may be used to implement the state of objects. For a lot of functional languages this is idiomatic.

Comment: @slebetman That's true. But the question is tagged as object oriented.

Comment: Yes, I meant object oriented functional languages. Like Lisp or Tcl or Javascript.

Comment: Is this also true for javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Code is part of the static data associated with the class.

Typically eEach class has a function table that references the virtual (aka. overridable) functions and each object has a pointer to the function table of its instance class. So the collection of instance methods are coalesced into a single pointer in the object.

So when calling a method the compiler looks into the table of the object and finds the correct function.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler might inline your code, but the copy that makes is not passed around with the instance.  The copy is physically stored within the code of the call site.  Likewise templates create a duplicate copy (except for the substituted types) for each different type of template instantiated, but those are not passed around with the instance either.

Under certain circumstances the instance's memory will contain a function *pointer*, but I don't know any language implementations that store the actual instructions with the instance.  Even in languages where functions are first-class and conceptually you are doing something like returning a closure from another function, the executable instructions are stored statically, and you're just passing around a pointer to those instructions and whatever state you need in context.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be objectively answered without knowing the language.

Here are explanations for two languages which cover many of the generally important points.

**C++**

Typically, some code will be duplicated while other code will not. Inline functions will of course be duplicated, and this includes any code in the class declaration which is implicitly inline. Code that is defined separately will not be duplicated.

Template classes (e.g. STL containers) are normally duplicated since they normally have the declaration and definition combined (see previous point).

Linkers can perform their own optimizations to combine code like this, although in practice I do not believe this is common.

Without a JVM or CLR to monkey around with memory at run time, whatever is compiled is highly likely to be what is loaded in memory at run time.

**Java**

Byte code will not be duplicated (i.e. in `.class` files). Due to the nature of class files being able to be compiled and manipulated separately, there will be no duplication or optimization across classes. However, the JIT compiler is free to inline code at runtime, which would duplicate it in memory.

Sources: [Java HotSpot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) - [JRockit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15058/underst_jit.htm) (there are quite a few references but very little official Oracle documentation on this topic)

Comment: Do you have any references for Java part of your question? I'm not sure how inlining has anything to do with the question.

Comment: if a method is inlined, it will not be stored only once in memory. I will dig up the reference for the JIT part later when I have time.

Comment: I added some references. There are quite a few out there, but very little documentation to serve as a primary reference.

Comment: @MainMa: Copying the method's code into the calling method is pretty much the *definition* of "inlining". So, yes, as soon as you have inlining, you have duplicate copies of the callee method. And pretty much every serious language implementation *does* perform inlining, because that is one of the most important and most basic optimizations. It does not just remove the dispatch and call overhead, it more importantly gives the compiler a nice big chunk of straight-line code with no jumps and no calls, which is what optimizers *love*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I know what inlining is. I just don't understand how is that related to the question, which is about the existence or not of the duplication of methods within every instance of a class.

Comment: @MainMa: The question is not a very good fit for the SE format, because it is not just one question but many questions rolled into one, and one of those questions is "do I have the code only once in memory?" And the answer to that sub-question is: no, because of (possible) inlining.

Comment: There are C++ compilers which compile to JVM bytecode, CIL bytecode, ECMAScript source code, and many other crazy things. I wouldn't count out the fact that a C++ program may be run on a platform which performs dynamic inlining and thus dynamic duplication of code. Note also, that in another sense code might be duplicated: a de-optimizing JIT compiler must keep the original code around in addition to the compiled code. I.e. the HotSpot JVM can make unsafe optimizations and then de-optimize back to bytecode, which means it needs to keep both the bytecode and the native code version in memory.

Comment: I honestly flipped a (mental) coin whether to vote to close the question or to answer it, and these comments illustrate exactly why I struggled. So many things are technically possible, regardless of whether or not they happen in practice. Even then, these things (inlining) can be argued one of many ways.